# How to write a SQL query have multiple summed columns in the result table?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

For example, there are 2 tables:

SERIES: with 3 relevant columns (2 teams are in a series):
series_id, team1_id and team2_id

RESULTS: with 3 relevant columns:
series_id, team_id (and time)

Each time a team wins a game of a SERIES, a row is inserted into the RESULTS table.

I must know the current score of each SERIES. So I'll need to join the tables on series_id and on team id.  However i want a result that looks like this:

```
series team1 team2
------------------
1        4     3
2        3     1
3        2     4
```

I do not understand how to get multiple columns in the result table, both of which store SUMs of conditional rows from the input tables. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Join the tables on `series_id`, then group by series and count the number of times the winning team matches the respective participants in the series (in MySQL one can use `SUM(boolean expression)` to perform the count, since `TRUE` equates to `1` and `FALSE` to `0`):

```
SELECT   series_id,
         SUM(RESULTS.team_id = SERIES.team1_id) AS team1,
         SUM(RESULTS.team_id = SERIES.team2_id) AS team2
FROM     SERIES LEFT JOIN RESULTS USING (series_id)
GROUP BY series_id
```